# A Wordpress gallery for all types of media?

Tags: wordpress, gallery

How can I display any type of media within a gallery in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question, its got extra comments. But I'll copy the important things to answer your question - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11662/get-all-images-in-media-gallery

So this would get all attachments in the media library;

```
$media_query = new WP_Query(
array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    )
);
$list = array();
foreach ($media_query->posts as $post) {
    $list[] = wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID);
}
// do something with $list here;
```

Or just get all items of a specific type;

```
$query_images_args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
    $images[]= $image->guid;
}
```

Comment: maybe i can,t understand your answer....but i want a gallery that display all type of media such as images,videos and flash files.....